# Am I wrong to make directory executable?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am writing a file upload using Zend_Form_Element_File(). I created a directory called `users` in the `public` directory. When I load the file, I got an error saying page is not found. I check the directory and saw that the permission is `drwxr-xr-x`. So I change the permission to `drwxrw-rw-` and load the page again. The page loads properly. But when I upload a file, it produces an error again. So I finally change the permission to `drwxrwxrwx` and everything runs properly.
My question is that am I doing the usual way that others are doing? I found it strange to make a directory executable.
Can someone explain whether I'm doing it correct? I am just learning Zend framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directories **must** be executable if a program should be able to "enter" it. Entering a directory basically means accessing any file/directory below that directory.

Having "read" access to a folder allows you to list its contents - what "write" access does is pretty obvious.

However, for security reasons you should check if `drwxrwx---` (`770`) is not sufficient; often your user and the webserver share a common group. If that's the case, there's no need to give any access to "world".

It would be even better to run your scripts as the same user as you - by using fastcgi that wouldn't be too hard, but if you are on shared hosting you usually do not have the necessary access to do this.

Comment: Actually, no, executable directories allow 'browsing' the dir and listing its contents. A directory only has to be readable to traverse it and access a subdir/file that you KNOW the full path/filename of.

Comment: I would argue for the webserver being an account that can't login and reducing permissions to 700 or lower.  if you chown with webserver:webserver it will be fine (in my experiences)

Comment: @MarcB: That's wrong. Here's the proof: https://paste.aeum.net/show/47/ - while this does not access a file inside, accessing `.` and `..` is no different from accessing a file.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: That requires him to have root access and will prevent him from accessing his files via non-root shell/ftp.

Comment: so it would make more sense for the following: webserver:users 740 ?

Comment: @MarcB, if you are running under mod_php5 rather than FastCGI, suEXEC or suPHP then any files created by the script use the HTTP service UID/GID not yours.  I help administer a site set up like this.  You need to give the public directory 777 privilege, create the users directory with a script (or sudo chown it if you have sudo access) and then lock public back down to 755 or 711.  This will mean that you can only write/delete files through a script of course.

Comment: SuPHP uses CGI which is slow as hell compared to pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you set permissions on the directory it is so they cascade down to the files within via extended ACLS in the majority of cases.  The issue that I see immediately is that you have granted world access which is a bad idea.  The only user that needs permissions to the directory (700 at max) is going to be your web server.  So I would revert security to be 700 asap.

Comment: On most systems the webserver user differs from the shell/ftp user. In this case the folder needs `770` or even `777` to be writable by php scripts unless it was created by the webserver itself (which would make it readonly to your ftp/shell though)

Comment: If you ever want to delete something: Yes. Besides that, to create the folder in the first place you need to grant group/world write permissions to the parent folder and then revoke it after creating the folder from your php script. Not hard but still a mess.